# How to properly use "as an" vs. "with an"

Tags: word-usage

I have a situation.

*He identifies himself `as a` musician, finding his inspirations in nature.*
OR
*He identifies himself `with a` musician, finding his inspirations in nature.*

which of these is correct please and why? thanks,

Comment: Both are correct; "he identifies as a musician" means that he considers himself to be a musician, while "he identifies with a musician" means that there is a musician that he considers himself to have many similar characteristics to.

Comment: it's all clear now, can you please answer the question in order to validate? many thanks.

Comment: Just as soon as I can find a source for my answer other than "I'm a native English speaker." :)

Comment: lol, u're unsure? :)

Comment: No, I'm certain, but a good answer on StackExchange has evidence and references to back it up.

Comment: now I got it! anyway, I think that being a native English speaker, it's pretty enough in this case :) I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are grammatically correct.

"*He identifies himself `as a` musician*" means that he considers himself to be a musician.

> [identify](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/identify?q=identify) (v): 1. establish or indicate who or what (someone or something) is

"*He identifies himself `with a` musician*" means that there is another musician that he considers himself to have many similar characteristics to.

> [identify](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/identify?q=identify) (v): 2. associate someone or something closely with; regard as having strong links with